# How to check EditButton/EditMode state in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, environment-variables, editmode

I have the following test codes. But when Edit button tapped Text doesn't change. I could not find anything about that. How to check/control editButton/editMode state changes?

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var list = [1,2,3,4,5]
    @State private var selection = Set<Int>()
    @Environment(\.editMode) var mode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(list, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    if mode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false {
                        Text("Editing")
                    } else {
                        Text("Not Editing")
                    }
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `.environment` with `@State` mode.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var list = [1,2,3,4,5]
    @State private var selection = Set<Int>()
    @State var mode: EditMode = .inactive //< -- Here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(list, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
            }
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Text(mode == .active ? "Editing" : "Not Editing")
                }
            }.environment(\.editMode, $mode) //< -- Here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Also can I use the editMode property where defined in TestView on another view by @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode: Binding<EditMode>

Comment: @KenanNur Not sure. But maybe yes

Comment: Make sure that the .environment() modifier is placed after the .toolbar() modifier.