# Can't get EditButton to work properly in my List

Tags: swiftui

I am currently learning Swift and for an assignment we have to create a simple application. I am trying to get the EditButton() for my master list. I have added the EditButton() to the navigation bar, however, when I click it, the locations in the ForEach go into edit mode, but not the "Test" text, and the environment variable doesn't update.

This is my current code I am using to test:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct LocationMasterListView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest (sortDescriptors: [], animation: .default)
    private var locations: FetchedResults<Location>
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Test")
            
            //Check for edit
            if (editMode?.wrappedValue == .active){
                Text("is editing")
            }
            else{
                Text("not editing")
            }
            
            
            ForEach(locations) {
                location in
                NavigationLink(destination: LocationDetailView(location: location)){
                    HStack{
                        MasterImageView(location: location)
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text(location.locationName)
                            Text(location.locationSuburb)
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteLocation)
        }.navigationTitle("Favourite Places")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: Button("+"){
                addLocation()
            })
            
    }
}
```

The location list item that is created in the ForEach shows the delete button and that works fine, but not the test text, and the if statement stays on "not editing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete button does not appear for "Test" because it is not modified with [`onDelete`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicviewcontent/ondelete(perform:)), like your `ForEach` is.

To be modified with `onDelete`, the view needs to be a [`DynamicViewContent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicviewcontent), which is how SwiftUI handles editing. But `Text` does not conform to that. You can make a `DynamicViewContent` by using a `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(0..<1) { _ in
    Text("Test")
}.onDelete { _ in
    // do something when Test is deleted
}
```

As for why the "is/not editing" text is not working, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68104918/5133585). In short, you should use `.environment(\.editMode)` and a `@State` to track the edit mode.

```
@State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
// ...

// modifying the List
.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
```